# Type error in typescript react-query and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

interface UserUrl {
  url: string;
}


function Upload() {
  const global_ping = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

  function short() {
    const data = { url: url };
    mutation.mutate(data);
  }
  function ChangeInInput(event: any) {
    setUrl(event.target.value);
  }

    const mutation = useMutation<any, Error, UserUrl>(
    async (userUrl: UserUrl) => {
        try {
        const response = await fetch(global_ping, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(userUrl),
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorData = await response.json();
            throw new Error(errorData.message || "An error occurred");
        }

        return await response.json();
        } catch (error: any) {
        throw new Error(error.message || "An error occurred");
        }
    },
    {
        onSuccess: (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("Done");
        },
        onError: (error: Error) => {
        console.log(error);
        },
    }
    );




  return (
    <>
      <input
        placeholder="Enter The Url To Be Shortned"
        value={url}
        onChange={ChangeInInput}
      ></input>
      <button onClick={short}>Shorten!</button>
      <h1></h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default Upload;
```

so this is a component for my React.ts app. And I am specifically looking at:

```
const mutation = useMutation<any, Error, UserUrl>(
    async (userUrl: UserUrl) => {
        try {
        const response = await fetch(global_ping, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(userUrl),
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorData = await response.json();
            throw new Error(errorData.message || "An error occurred");
        }

        return await response.json();
        } catch (error: any) {
        throw new Error(error.message || "An error occurred");
        }
    },
    {
        onSuccess: (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("Done");
        },
        onError: (error: Error) => {
        console.log(error);
        },
    }
    );
```

And I am getting and error in the mutation stating that:

```
Type '(userUrl: UserUrl) => Promise<any>' has no properties in common with type 'UseMutationOptions<any, Error, UserUrl, unknown>'.ts(2559)
```

how can I fix my code please help me this code above it is just making a http post request to a backend django, but I am not able to figure out how to solve this problem, can anyone please help me fix this problem?

Comment: You are using `fetch` not `axios`. Cannot reproduce the error. Please create a running demo using stackblitz